# How to find next 2 or 4 null keys in dictionary with starting index

Tags: c#

I have `Dictionary<ushort, ushort>` and let's say I have `KeyValuePair` from json file with index `43001` and value. If the value is `float` I have to convert the float to 2 ushort values and store them in the dictionary where the higher order bytes will be at `43001` and the lower order bytes will be stored at `43002`. If it's `double` I have to store it as 4 ushorts. This is fine, I know how to do it. If I have another `float` value with the same starting index of `43001` I have to store it starting with `43003`. If `43001` is already present, how can I find next 2 available index (or 4 for double)  after `43001` till `65535`.

I know I can do something like

```
for (ushort i = 43001; i < 65535; i += 2)
{
   if (!dict.ContainsKey(i) && !dict.ConainsKey(i + 1))
   {
       return //whatever;
   }
}
```

and the same for double, but I think there is more elegant and better way.

Comment: Having a hard time to understand that data structure, but hmm, you probably could use a `Dictionary<ushort, List<ushort>>`. Then you could just add the other values using the same index.

Comment: When you say better do you mean efficiency of finding the gap? If you use an OrderedDictionary then you can scan the Keys to find a gap but at first glance you can't e.g. binary search to find 43001 to start searching, you'll need to scan the whole list to get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, something like

```
var start = 43001;
var end = 65535;
var range = end - start;
var step = 2;
var nextSlot = Enumerable.Range(0, range / step)
    .Select(i => (ushort)(start + i * step))
    .First(i =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, step)
            .Select(ii => (ushort)(ii + i))
            .All(iii => !dict.ContainsKey(iii)));
```